# Where to buy non-kindle-format (epub,azw) e-books which look like the printed books?

Tags: pdf

If I want to buy e-copy of academic books, most of the publishers (Oxford, Cambridge, etc.) direct to amazon store or allow epub version. However, I do not want the e-pub or other formats (e.g. azw) as the ebook in this format does not have the actual pagination and format of the printed copy.

So, is there a store or place where I can buy the e-copy of the book (preferably in pdf format) which actually looks like the printed copy (having the actual page numbers and format/style of the printed copy)?

I am aware that some of the kindle books do come with both "locations" and "actual page numbers" to avoid the above problem. However, this is feature is not available for the majority of the books (as I open the sample version and check). Also, I miss the style/formatting of the printed book.

Answer (score 1):

Among some of the major sources that note available formats, there is Google Books and ebooks.com. Since you mention academic publishers, ebooks.com is perhaps the overall best place.

https://www.ebooks.com/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes...others have suggested the same.